# WCF service Process.Start under network service account impersonating as a different user

Tags: c#, wcf, process, credentials, network-service

I have Wcf Service hosted in IIS, Windows Server 2008 R2, using an AppPool .NET 4.0 with NETWORK SERVICE Identity.

My Wcf Service has a method that calls an command EXE using Process.Start.

I need use an different user as credentials for execute command EXE, an domain user account.

I try execute it but it doesn't works for me: it seems not execute the command EXE.

update: process exited, but not execute code

I get errors like:

exit code -1073741502

and eventvwr:

```
            Process Information:
            Process ID:            0xc50
            Process Name:      C:\DeployTools\DeployTools.Commands.Ejecutar.exe
            Exit Status:            0xc0000142
```

> The appplication was unable to start correctly (0xC0000142). Click OK
>   to close the application

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
        StreamReader sr = null;
        StreamReader serr = null;

        try
        {
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(MY_COMMAND_EXE);
            psi.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(MY_COMMAND_EXE);
            psi.Arguments = arguments;
            psi.Domain = DOMAIN;
            psi.UserName = USER_IN_DOMAIN;
            psi.Password = SecureStringHelper.ToSecureString(pwd);

            psi.LoadUserProfile = true;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;

            psi.ErrorDialog = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

            using (Process pr = Process.Start(psi))
            {
                sr = pr.StandardOutput;
                serr = pr.StandardError;

                if (!pr.HasExited)
                {
                    pr.WaitForExit(300000);
                }
                output = pr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                errors = pr.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                exitCode = pr.ExitCode;

                return output;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return "EXCEPCIÓN: " + exc.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (sr != null)
            {
                sr.Close();
                sr.Dispose();
                sr = null;
            }

            if (serr != null)
            {
                serr.Close();
                serr.Dispose();
                serr = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you check your event log size, as the last 4 digits of the exit code '1502' means the event log / error log file is full. If this is the issue you can fix it with - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/fixing-the-event-log-is-full-error-on-windows-xp/

Comment: That is not the problem. I check event log, is empty. Clear log before each test.

Comment: assembly 'AsproLock' has a strong name ?

Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'AsproLock' does not have a strong name 
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/if_warden/tree/master/lib/AsproLock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to add a reference to [AsproLock.dll](http://www.asprosys.com/resources/projects/asprolock/default.aspx) and associated code in order to permit the user account to have access to the running resource.

```
            //The following security adjustments are necessary to give the new 
            //process sufficient permission to run in the service's window station
            //and desktop. This uses classes from the AsproLock library also from 
            //Asprosys.
            IntPtr hWinSta = NativeMethods.GetProcessWindowStation();
            WindowStationSecurity ws = new WindowStationSecurity(hWinSta,
              System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.Access);
            ws.AddAccessRule(new WindowStationAccessRule(userPassDto.Usuario,
                WindowStationRights.AllAccess, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
            ws.AcceptChanges();

            IntPtr hDesk = NativeMethods.GetThreadDesktop(NativeMethods.GetCurrentThreadId());
            DesktopSecurity ds = new DesktopSecurity(hDesk,
                System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections.Access);
            ds.AddAccessRule(new DesktopAccessRule(userPassDto.Usuario,
                DesktopRights.AllAccess, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
            ds.AcceptChanges();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcessWindowStation();

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(int dwThreadId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
```

**The Perils and Pitfalls of Launching a Process Under New Credentials by Asprosys**

This isn't a common need but it also isn't that rare, so I thought I had better post this step by step guide to troubleshooting the launching of a process under impersonated credentials. This is based on using the Start method of the .Net Process class but it is also applicable to the underlying API calls: CreateProcessWithLogonW and CreateProcessWithTokenW.

**Access Denied** - The first attempt and an access denied exception right off the bat. This is the most common initial problem and is caused by the fact that the service is running under the LOCAL SYSTEM account. Strangely, the SYSTEM account is the most powerful account on the computer but one of the few things it cannot do is launch a process using CreateProcessWithLogonW which is the API underlying the call to Process.Start. So change your service account to Local Service, it's probably the more appropriate account anyway.

**Access Denied Again** - Aargh, I thought we solved this. Oops, double check the permissions on the application that you are trying to launch. Remember that the system tries to access the application file as the user account that the process will be running under, not the service account.

**Invalid Directory Error** - What? All the paths are correct. All the directories are spelled correctly, no invalid characters. This is an incredibly annoying error and is not very consistent. Usually when we run a process we don't bother setting the WorkingDirectory property and just accept the default from the parent process. When starting a process with new credentials you can't do that, you must explicitly set a path for the WorkingDirectory or you'll get a "The directory name is invalid." Win32Exception.

**Failure**: No Error? - Process.Start handles the creation of the Environment block for the new process for you quite well. So this is a problem only if you are using the underlying API. When calling one of the CreateProcess* APIs it is normal to leave the lpEnvironment parameter as NULL and have the system use the default of copying the block from the parent process. But when launching under new credentials you must create an environment block explicitly, either manually or using CreateEnvironmentBlock. What makes this worse is, if you leave this out the CreateProcess* call will fail but GetLastError will return ERROR_SUCCESS and if you make an error creating your environment block there will be no error but the process may just not run at all.

**Application Failed to Initialize Properly** - No more exceptions, you've solved all the problems and the process has been launched. Oops again, where is the process? Check the event log (or you may have received an Application Error pop-up). There should be an entry for Application Error that says that your process was the faulting application, either user32.dll or kernel32.dll was the faulting module and the exception was: 0xC0000142. There may be some minor variation in this but basically it is saying that your application could not initialize. The reason for this is that on initialization, before any application code is run, all processes are attached to a Window Station and all threads are attached to a Desktop but the user you are launching under does not have permission to access the Window Station and Desktop in which your process is being launched, ergo it can't initialize. The security descriptors for the Window Station and Desktop must be adjusted to give AllAccess permission to the user the process is being launched under. This is a devil to do directly in .Net, so you might find the security wrapper classes here useful.

**No More Errors** - Really, no more errors, your process should be running smoothly now. There may be some variations in what you need to do based on who the user is (for instance an administrator will already have the correct permissions in some cases) or what kind of session you are launching in. But following these steps should make your life smooth and easy (well maybe not your whole life).

References:

[The Perils and Pitfalls of Launching a Process Under New Credentials](http://www.asprosys.com/Resources/omphalos/perilsandpitfalls.aspx)

[Aspro Lock - Access Control](http://www.asprosys.com/Resources/Projects/AsproLock/default.aspx)

[Code Samples](http://www.asprosys.com/Resources/Samples/codesamples.aspx)

[Creating New Process Under Alternate Credentials (createprocessasuser)](http://www.astahost.com/info/titssm-creating-process-alternate-credentials-createprocessasuser.html)

[processstart-hangs](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1b24fe9-96a2-4303-b185-17893a3fdea4/processstart-hangs-when-executed-via-sql-server)