# Exe stopped suddenly when calling from windows service

Tags: c#

I have written a windows service and i am calling one of my exe from this windows service.

new exe starting successfully ant getting stopped in 2-3 sec.

Can anyone suggest on it?

Comment: put some logging in application and see what is wrong!

Comment: new exe is running successfully. Its showing in task manager for few seconds. But its stopping automatically.

Comment: Add more info to your question.

Comment: We are calling one of my exe from windows service say blah.exe, i have used Process to start it. When service started it lauches that exe on server and executing only for few seconds only, not completing process.

If i run the exe directly from file system its working fine, facing problem only when i launch it from windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Launching apps from a Windows service via `Process.Start()` is not supported by Microsoft. It can sometimes work, but as you have seen, it is not reliable. `Process.Start()` is intended for launching applications from "interactive" processes, while services are considered "batch" processes.

To launch an application from a service, you will need to use Win32 API calls. An example of code that can do this can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15688675/1687106). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985036/1687106) may also provide some useful information.

Comment: Well, that's not really precise! We successfully run headless applications (console applications with hidden console window) from Windows services. What you mean is that GUI interaction is not supported anymore.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar, because it's too long to repost in a comment, please follow the link to the first linked answer - it gives the information a Microsoft Support engineer once gave me about this topic.

Comment: I think the important part in the Microsoft quote you didn't highlight is *when credentials are specified*. If you don't, the process will just be run under the same user the service runs under. As I said, your answer is correct for the "Desktop interactive" option that existed before Vista. You can not run desktop interactive applications from a Windows service since Vista. Your answer is incomplete in that it doesn't mention that you **can** run non-interactive simple console applications. You can even control them using the input/output streams.